# looping the local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to loop the local storage for the password and username to check if correct and alert a message if or if not.
The code is working well, but I don't know where to write the `"invalid username"` message because the loop goes through every record, so the messages pops ups for every record check until it finds it.
What I want is to pop up the message when the search is done.

Here is my code:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
    var username =$("#user").val();
    var password =$("#pass").val();
    var userCount = localStorage.getItem('userCount');  

    for (i=1;i<=userCount;i++) {
        var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user" + i));
        if((user.username == username)||(user.password == password)){
            alert("welcome "+username);
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Username");//this message keeps poping up on every record until username found
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the use-case for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a boolean variable to `true` when you find a match, and stop the loop using `break`. Otherwise, if the boolean is still `false` after the loop completes, no match was found.

```
$("#login").click(function(){
    var username =$("#user").val();
    var password =$("#pass").val();
    var userCount = localStorage.getItem('userCount');  
    var foundOne = false;

    for (i=1;i<=userCount;i++) {
        var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user" + i));
        if((user.username == username)&&(user.password == password)){
            foundOne = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(foundOne) {
        alert("welcome "+username);
        // other "welcome" code
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Username");
    }
});
```

NB, you may want to use the `&&` operator instead of `||` here:

```
(user.username == username)&&(user.password == password)
```

otherwise you may get a match for one user who has the same password as another.

Answer (score 1):

Put the loop inside a function.

Return true (or the user object) from that function if anything inside the loop matched.

Return false after the loop (which you'll only reach if nothing matches).

Handle your alert outside the function based on the return value of calling it.